# Disable specific function keys on Mac OS X

Tags: macos, keyboard-shortcuts, quicksilver

I recently got a new MacBook Pro, and this has different functions assigned to the f1-f12 keys than my old one. Specifically, it has a dimmer for the keyboard backlight, and now there is no more room to open dashboard.

I only really used dashboard for the translate widget, so I don't want to have it open as a space all the time, I just want it asinged to a function key.

I'v already written a simple app in applescript that opens mission controle, and I know how to use QuickSilver to run that app when a spesific key (or key combination) is pressed, the problem is that the f1-f12 keys all have a function assigned to them already by OSX. 
I know I can disable those by turning on "Use all F1, F2, etc. keys as standart function keys" in system preferences, but I only want to use one of them as a standart function key, (specifically f3) so I can use it as a keyboard shortcut in QuickSilver.

Is there any way of achieving this?

Comment: I found a solution that works on MacOS 14 Sonoma. https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/467229/16279, switch all keys back to F functions then bind some of them back to the shortcuts, and leave some as F keys.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After searching for a while I finally found it again :)

Check this app Function Flip - http://kevingessner.com/software/functionflip/
This app allows to switch individually the FN keys. Remember to go to Settings -> Security & Privacy -> Privacy tab -> Give access to FunctionFlip. Also, on the Preferences remember to add it to login for convenience (and start the service of course :)).

Credits go to Kevin Gessner for this amazing piece of software.

Comment: Awesome! Exactly what I was looking fore!

Comment: Good recommendation, works well (thank you Kevin Gessner!) - to install this preferences pane, you can use `cp -r FunctionFlip.prefPane ~/Library/PreferencePanes`.  Now I can stop a mis-hit Cmd-F1 from mirroring displays.

Comment: It install but doesnt start on macos 14 sonoma. does anyone know how to get it working or alternatives?